# Hartl Rails Tutorial - Chapter 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm completing the exercise to add a Contact page, but the testing fails on the page title.

Here is my testing file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get root" do
    get root_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | #{@base_title}"
  end
end
```

Here is the contact.html.erb file:

```
<% provide(:title, "Contact") %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>
  Contact the Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
</p>
```

I've also completed the following:

- Added the appropriate route
- Added the appropriate action

However I get this error message:

```
    test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.45s)
    <Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
    <About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Please also note that

- The page displays correctly, with the expected page title (Contact not About)
- I tested again using a completely new page, but had the same result with 'About' being returned in page title

Really not sure why it's returning this as I've followed Tutorial closely.  I want to progress in Tutorial, but if I cannot resolve this basic testing issue, I'm not sure I'll get very far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code on the second line of this code block.

```
  test "should get contact" do
    # get static_pages_about_url # This is wrong correct it to as below
    get static_pages_contact_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | #{@base_title}"
  end
```

You have given a test case to check the contact page title on the about url which obviously will fail the test.

You should be testing for contact page title on the contact url like above.

Make the change and you should get going!

Also a word of motivation, just keep going even if things don't make sense right now cause later they will. Cheers :)

Comment: thank you!  It's amazing I stared at this code for something like and hour and it was such a simple thing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might try to replace the line `get static_pages_about_url` (under `test "should get contact" do`) with:

```
get static_pages_contact_url
```

What happens is that your test is calling the wrong url (`about`, instead of `contact`), causing the error when checking the `<title>`.

Comment: thank you! I wouldn't want to spend any more time on something SO simple.